# Azure AD Connect Group Membership Not Syncing

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have Azure AD Connect installed, syncing to an Amazon Simple AD, configured for Pass Through authentication and SSO.

The Pass Through authentication and SSO work well. Users sync, groups sync, group membership does not sync. All groups appear empty and no users are a member of any groups (specifically groups that are sync'd okay). There is no nested group membership.

How can I troubleshoot this?

One other possibly relevant fact is that Password Synchronization didn't work at all. Users and Groups were sync'd but no one could log in (got an incorrect password error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon SimpleAD LDAP multi reference attributes aren't fully cross compatible with regular Active Directory when converted to binary, which is what the Azure AD Connect used to sync them. It's not possible without deeply customizing the sync process.